# How concat aws stack name with other string in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

Consider [serverless](https://serverless.com/) template

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:

    MyStateMachine:
      name: "#{AWS::StackName}SomeName"
```

Gives me:

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Resource name #{AWS::StackName}SomeName is non alphanumeric.
```

So this inlining does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this thread provide you with a solution? https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3184 especially the comment from seriouscoderone on May 6 might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing magical to it, you don't need the quotes try the following:

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:

    MyStateMachine:
      name: #{AWS::StackName}SomeName
```